# unable to get transaction using ious in when running corda 4.0 example

Tags: corda

I am unable to view transactions of IOUS when running the corda 4.0 example.

I have tried in many ways to change the code but the given example itself not working.

http://localhost:50005/api/example/my-ious

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Success (erased) -> value() -> net.corda.core.node.services.Vault$Page (erased) -> states(java.util.List>) -> java.util.List>> -> net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef -> state(net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState) -> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState -> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> Cannot construct evolution serializer for remote type com.example.state.IOUState: net.corda.core.contracts.LinearState, net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState, net.corda.core.schemas.QueryableState borrower (optional): net.corda.core.identity.Party name: net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name commonName (optional): java.lang.String country: java.lang.String locality: java.lang.String organisation: java.lang.String organisationUnit (optional): java.lang.String state (optional): java.lang.String owningKey: java.security.PublicKey lender (optional): net.corda.core.identity.Party name: net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name commonName (optional): java.lang.String country: java.lang.String locality: java.lang.String organisation: java.lang.String organisationUnit (optional): java.lang.String state (optional): java.lang.String owningKey: java.security.PublicKey linearId: net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier externalId (optional): java.lang.String id: java.util.UUID value (optional): java.lang.Integer Local type int of property value is not assignable from remote type class java.lang.Intege

Comment: what example? :-)

Comment: i have made a transaction and executed this http://localhost:50005/api/example/my-ious

Comment: Can you provide a link to "corda 4.0 example" please

Comment: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example

Comment: is this solved? I am facing the same issue any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The repository referred to in this has been archived. Please use the most recent repository here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/cordapp-example.

It seems to be working fine.